# etale sheafification of exact forms

Tags: sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

We know that the set of differential forms together with restrictions is a sheaf. But what happens if we take the subset of exact forms and make its etale sheafification? Do we obtain a distinct sheaf?

Comment: I might be wrong, but aren't the sheafifications the same, iff the presheaves have the same stalks?

Comment: You get the sheaf of closed forms. Indeed, if $\mathcal{E}$ is the presheaf of exact form and $\mathcal{Z}$ the sheaf of closed form, then the inclusion $\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\mathcal{Z}$ is an isomorphism on stalks since any closed form is locally exact. Hence, the inclusion becomes an isomorphism after sheafification.

Comment: I think you are right klirk 5. Roland that was that missing to me. Thanks.